# How to solve parse error in pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, query

I am currently trying to add Point geometries into a table. My query is the following

```sql
    UPDATE postal_code.postal_codes 
    SET    geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || lon || ' ' || lat || ')',4269);
```

I keep on getting a error message that says the following

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT("l" <-- parse error at position 8 within geometry
SQL state: XX000
```

Any tips on how to solve this error?

Comment: Please do not use ALLCAPS in your question title. This is considered to be rude ("SHOUTING"), and will generate downvotes. Error messages should always be included in the question as text (images can't be indexed)

Comment: Thank you for the tips

Comment: Could it be that the lat/long columns are TEXT, and some of them contain an empty string?

Comment: Is the lon column a string or a double?

Comment: You should probably review the output of your WKT candidate *before* pumping it into an UPDATE statement, by doing a `SELECT` on the calculated WKT).  The error message indicates the syntax failure is there.

Comment: The lon column is a character varying and they are all populated and have no empty strings.

Comment: But do they cast cleanly to double? The error indicates that they do not.

Comment: yes I believe so

Comment: I figured it out; thank you everyone for you help it is greatly appreciated